# Testflight build with new bundle identifier and provisioning profile

Tags: provisioning-profile, testflight, bundle-identifier

I have application in TestFlight with the following details.

- Bundle identifier: a
- Provisioning profile: profile with a as bundle identifier.

Now I need to upload a new application in TestFlight.

- Bundle identifier: a.b
- Provisioning profile: NEW provisioning profile with b as bundle identifier.

Questions:

1. For the already existing application in TestFlight, the current version number is 1.0.1 and build number is 9. Now for the new TestFlight application, since bundle identifier is changed, is it fine If I start the version number from 1.0.1 and build number as 0?
2. Will I need to create a new TestFlight project to for this application?
3. Will my production application with bundle identifier as "a" will get impacted?

Answer (score 0):

Each app in TestFlight is tied to a unique bundleID. To upload a new application in TestFlight, you'll need a new application setup in TestFlight, with a different bundleID.

In terms of versioning, you can start from any number. It doesn't have to start at 1.0. The same is true for the build number as well.

Because the app with bundle identifier `a.b` is going to be a different app than the production app (`a`), it should not be impacted.